# ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT" , SQL Triggers, protocol table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to save rows that I delete into a separate table, but I am facing constant errors. I am using postgresSQL (terminal).

Here is what the original table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE person_Lives_there 
(
    pId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cityId BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

And my protocol table

```
CREATE TABLE Protocol
(
    pId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cityId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    deletedOn TIMESTAMP
);
```

Now, my trigger should look like this, but it constantly gives me errors, right now:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deletion
AFTER DELETE
ON person_Lives_there
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO Protocol (pId, cityId, deletedOn)
    VALUES (old.pId, old.cityId, current_date());
```

I have also already tried to have a trigger and a function, but that led to constant error messages with the function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you have a typo: `deltedOn`

Comment: Hey, thanks. However, the error still pops up :(

Comment: You have defined your trigger in a wrong way.  This is not PostgreSQL syntaxe for triggers take a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL allows only procedural triggers. SQL statement triggers are not supported.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_Lives_there_delete_trg_fx()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Protocol
    VALUES(old.PId, old.cityId, current_date());
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER person_Lives_there_delete_trg
   AFTER DELETE ON person_Lives_there
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE person_Lives_there_fx();
```